# How do you share diagrams in Valentina Studio (DB)

Tags: database, erd, valentina-studio

I'm just getting familiar with Valentina Studio. It seems like a very useful tool--with easy drag/drop diagrams that stay in sync with actual schemas.

In my particular case, I'm using it with postgres. What's not clear to me is, **where are diagrams stored, and how do I share them?**

AFAIKT the only export mechanism is diagram-by-diagram. This will be a nightmare to share with other developers if I create a couple dozen diagrams. At the same time, all of my diagrams magically appear every time I start the software. I haven't figured out if they're being stored in the local filesystem somewhere or buried in the sql server somewhere. So far my physical and google searches of turned up nothing.

The available info on the product is pretty bleak, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the diagrams are being encoded and stored, per db connection, here:

~/.local/share/Paradigma\ Software/Valentina\ Studio/LocalData/Foreign/.../data.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's my current, hacky solution.

Each Valentina Studio connection results in a diagrams data file, in a subdirectory of:

```
~/.local/share/Paradigma\ Software/Valentina\ Studio/LocalData/Foreign/
```

So, I just copied this file (`data.conf`) into a directory of my source code repo and then kept Valentina Studio happy with a symlink.

Here's how a new developer gets access to the diagrams:

1. Create a new connection to your database (psql in my case)

   - This results in a directory containing a diagrams data file, such as:

     ```
     ~/.local/share/Paradigma\ Software/Valentina\ Studio/LocalData/Foreign/localhost%2Fpostgres%2F5432%2F%2F%2F%2F0%2Fmydb
     ```
2. Close Valentina Studio
3. Delete the existing diagrams config directory:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.local/share/Paradigma\ Software/Valentina\ Studio/LocalData/Foreign/localhost%2Fpostgres%2F5432%2F%2F%2F%2F0%2Fmydb
   ```
4. Add a symlink pointing to your source-controlled copy of the diagrams data file:

   ```
   ln -s /my/source/code/valentina-diagrams-data ~/.local/share/Paradigma\ Software/Valentina\ Studio/LocalData/Foreign/localhost%2Fpostgres%2F5432%2F%2F%2F%2F0%2Fmydb
   ```

Now any changes to the diagrams will affect your source-controlled copy.

Fortunately, the `data.conf` only seems to contain diagram data so far, but who knows what else might show up in there down the line.

I expect that this same approach will work on Windows using [directory junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).